# Spring Boot Read CSV and update DB table

Tags: spring-boot, csv, save, filereader

I have create a REST API POST in order to read a file csv and than update my postgres table in this way:

```
@Override
public void insertDataFromCSV(CsvDataInputBean csvDataInputBean)
        throws IllegalStateException, FileNotFoundException {

    String path = csvDataInputBean.getPath();
    log.info("INPUT PATH ", csvDataInputBean.getPath().toString());

    List<CsvPojo> csvFile = new CsvToBeanBuilder<CsvPojo>(new FileReader(path)).withType(CsvPojo.class).build()
            .parse();

    UserEntity userEntity = new UserEntity();

    for (CsvPojo csv : csvFile) {
        log.info("CSV User Name: ", csv.getName());
        log.info("CSV User Surname: ", csv.getSurname());
        log.info("CSV User Gender: ", csv.getGender());
        log.info("CSV User Age: ", csv.getAge());
        log.info("CSV User CF: ", csv.getCf());
        log.info("CSV User Mail: ", csv.getMail());
        log.info("CSV User Address: ", csv.getAddress());

        userEntity.setId(csv.getId());
        userEntity.setName(csv.getName());
        userEntity.setSurname(csv.getSurname());
        userEntity.setGender(csv.getGender());
        userEntity.setAge(csv.getAge());
        userEntity.setCf(csv.getCf());
        userEntity.setMail(csv.getMail());
        userEntity.setAddress(csv.getAddress());
        userRepository.save(userEntity);
        userRepository.flush();
        log.info("Saved the Record: ", csv.getId());
    }

}
```

But when I try to test on Postman I get this error:

I don't see the log with the value of the fields:

```
2023-05-02 19:31:55.941  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Name: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.941  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Surname: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.941  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Gender: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.942  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Age: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.942  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User CF: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.942  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Mail: 
2023-05-02 19:31:55.942  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : CSV User Address: 
2023-05-02 19:31:56.043  INFO 19836 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.u.u.service.impl.UserServiceImpl       : Saved the Record:
```

Saving to db is not correct, it has misalignments. In particular, it does not set the name and sets the name instead of the surname.

The CSV file has these values:
Id,Name,Surname,Gender,Age,Cf,Mail,Address
15,Pablo,Escobar,male,52,PBLESC65T85P456H,pabloescobar@hotmail.it,Via Medein 27

But in the DB I see:
[image: Image DB]

UserEntity and CSVPojo are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mt_user")
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    @Column(name = "cf")
    private String cf;

    @Column(name = "mail")
    private String mail;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

public class CsvPojo {

    @CsvBindByName(column = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "name")
    private String name;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "name")
    private String surname;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "gender")
    private String gender;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "age")
    private int age;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "cf")
    private String cf;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "mail")
    private String mail;

    @CsvBindByName(column = "address")
    private String address;
```

How Could I solve it?